# How to capture the specific text inside the URL?

Tags: java, url, webdriver

I have capture the current URL on the page.
using :

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

Now I want a specific text inside this string. Let say

```
String url = http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5-gtsdenpE
```

and I want

1. Capture and store the current page URL in String URL. (Done)
2. Capture the text in the URL after "v" and store it in String emb. (??)

I am using JAVA to write my scripts on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
 String fullURL = http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5-gtsdenpE;
 String emb = fullURL.split("\\?v=")[1];
```

Comment: Error : java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 0
?v=

Comment: Forget to escape the `?`. Try now!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want I guess-

```
    String string = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5-gtsdenpE";
    URL url = new URL(string);
    System.out.println(url.getQuery());
```

Handle the exception appropriately.

In case you don't want to use URL class, just search for the first index of ? and then use substring() to get the string after that.

```
    System.out.println(string.substring(string.indexOf("?")+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Url url = new Url(driver.getCurrentUrl());
Map<String, String[]> params = parameterMapFromString(url.getQuery());
String v = params.get("v")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are requirement is static and you are sure that you have to get the value  after "v" than you can try this also

```
String emb  = url.substring(url.indexOf("v"), url.length()).trim();
```

Comment: @user2172723: welcome to stackoverflow I would really appreciate if you accept any one answer(which was helpful to you) out of the  answers suggested over here by different users. for more details visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq  happy coding :)